# Does tf.zeros() return tf.get_variable()?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, gradient-descent

Trying to understand the `SGD` optimization code in keras optimizers ([source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizers.py)).  In the `get_updates` module, we have:

```
# momentum
shapes = [K.int_shape(p) for p in params]
moments = [K.zeros(shape) for shape in shapes]
self.weights = [self.iterations] + moments
for p, g, m in zip(params, grads, moments):
    v = self.momentum * m - lr * g  # velocity
    self.updates.append(K.update(m, v))
```

where `K = keras.backend`.  Now, since `moments` is set to a list a zero tensors, and `m` is an iteration of this list, why doesn't `m` always evaluate to a zero tensor in the line `v = self.momentum * m - lr * g`?

Now I looked up the code for `keras.backend.zeros` for tensorflow ([source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py)), and `keras.backend.zeros` returns [`tf.zeros`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/zeros), which apparently returns a constant tensor of zeros.  (Edit: Or returns a `tf.Variable` initialized with `tf.zeros` if shape is specified.)

My intuition would be that it would return something like `tf.get_variable()` with an initiatilizer of zeros, and thus the tensor would not be overwritten each time.  Instead a tensor with name `m` would just keep getting updated by `K.update()`.

So does `tf.zeros()` actually behave like `tf.get_variable()` with a zero initialization?  Is there something else I am missing?

**Edit:** So even if shapes are specified, source code linked above still seems to return a new tensor variable, not reuse the existing one (i.e. using `get_variable()`), which would seem difficult anyway since no name was specified.  Still confused as to why the existing variable is returned as opposed to a new tensor variable of zeros.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed the right `K.zeros` function. Here's the source code in keras 2.1 ([`keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/keras-2/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L494)):

````py
def zeros(shape, dtype=None, name=None):
    """Instantiates an all-zeros variable and returns it.

    # Arguments
        shape: Tuple of integers, shape of returned Keras variable
        dtype: String, data type of returned Keras variable
        name: String, name of returned Keras variable

    # Returns
        A variable (including Keras metadata), filled with `0.0`.

    # Example
    ```python
        >>> from keras import backend as K
        >>> kvar = K.zeros((3,4))
        >>> K.eval(kvar)
        array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
               [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
               [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
    ```
    """
    if dtype is None:
        dtype = floatx()
    tf_dtype = tf.as_dtype(dtype)
    return variable(tf.constant_initializer(0., dtype=tf_dtype)(shape),
                    dtype, name)
````

As you can see, it actually returns the **variable initialized with zeros**, not the constant zeros tensor. The [documentation](https://keras.io/backend/#zeros) states the same:

> Instantiates an all-zeros variable and returns it.

---

**Edit**: the answer to the follow-up question.

This is actually a very good observation: you are right, the subsequent calls to `Optimizer.get_updates(loss, params)` will create *new* variables, assign *new* ops to `self.updates` and *new* weights to `self.weights`. In some sense, `get_updates` method is a part of optimizer's constructor.

But here's how it works: this method is called exactly *once* per model instance. It returns the list of update ops that are applied many times in a loop for different batches, but the ops themselves stay the same. Here's the relevant code of the `Model` class ([`keras/engine/training.py`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/engine/training.py#L979)):

```py
def _make_train_function(self):
    ...
    if self.train_function is None:
        ...
        with K.name_scope('training'):
            with K.name_scope(self.optimizer.__class__.__name__):
                training_updates = self.optimizer.get_updates(
                    params=self._collected_trainable_weights,
                    loss=self.total_loss)
            updates = self.updates + training_updates + self.metrics_updates
            # Gets loss and metrics. Updates weights at each call.
            self.train_function = K.function(inputs,
                                             [self.total_loss] + self.metrics_tensors,
                                             updates=updates,
                                             name='train_function',
                                             **self._function_kwargs)
```

`self.optimizer.get_updates(...)` is called exactly once to construct the `train_function`.

Feel free to examine other optimizers and check that they all prepare the weights and update ops inside `get_updates()` method.

Comment: I clicked your link and it brought me to the same function I was at, https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L667.  This has `v = tf.zeros(shape=shape, dtype=tf_dtype, name=name)
    if py_all(v.get_shape().as_list()):
        return variable(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
    return v`

Comment: Corrected the link. The master diverged from 2.1, apparently.

Comment: Thanks.  So what does it mean that the master branch is now different?  Can we expect this to change in the future?

Comment: It's extended. The pydoc says: *"Note that if `shape` was symbolic, we cannot return a variable, and will return a dynamically-shaped tensor instead."* Ordinary cases like yours will behave the same way.

Comment: Sorry just one more question Maxim - how does Keras know to return the existing tensor list to `moments` and not a new list of zero tensors, if a name is not specified?  Any resource you could point me to would be appreciated.

Comment: @dashnick This is a good question! See the update to my answer